# MYsql query to show products with 0 quantity to the bottom

Tags: mysql, t-sql

I have a MYSQL database with a table Products.
Among other fields there are the **Qty** which is the quantity of the product and the **ProductCode** which is the product code.
Some of the products have 0 quantity.
I want to show these products to the bottom of the grid and the rest of the products (these are >0 ) to the top of the grid sorted by ProductCode.
If i say **order by Qty desc, productcode** then all the 0 products goes to the bottom but the order of productcode is not right.
If i say **order by productcode asc, Qty desc** then i have some 0 products to the top.
I tried with **Union**, first a query with all >0 and then a query <=0 but i saw that i cant have an order by in a Union.
Are there any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Union will work with subselects:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT Qty, Productcode FROM schema_name.Products WHERE Qty > 0 
               ORDER BY Productcode) AS a
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT Qty, Productcode FROM schema_name.Products WHERE Qty <= 0 
               ORDER BY Productcode) AS b ;
```

Comment: Yes that is. Thanks a lot